# Updating large number of rows

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a large number of rows in a SQL Server table. I need to select all those rows and run an update query for each of those rows. I need to know what's the best option do it from the following

1. run a select query and get a DataTable and use the following code in the application

   foreach(DataRow item in DataTable.Rows)
   {
   //perform update
   }
2. in the database level use a stored procedure, select the set of data and use SQL Server cursor to perform the update

Comment: Why do you need to do the update one row at the time? A set based solution is probably much more efficient.

Comment: How are you changing the data? Both of those option could be quite slow. But there are better options depending on the changes.

Comment: Use **option 3**: a **set-based** UPDATE statement in SQL. There's absolutely no need to pull down the data to the client for an update (option 1), and when updating on the server, you should **avoid the cursor** - it's slow, it's ugly, it's not needed in 99% of the cases anyway... also: how many rows are you talking about? Hundreds? Thousands? Millions?

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 vs option 2 means you work with disconnected dataset vs connected data readers.

As discussed other times here in SO in fact this means more memory needs at once on the client vs a connection kept open longer and smaller chunk of data transmitted more often while looping on results. Since your main focus is on the update of data i think both options are probably similar and if you have many records i would probably go for the second one, using datareader, to do not have to load all those records at once in a dataset.

As others already pointed out the best performances would be achieved having a set based update stored procedure to which you would pass certain parameters and all records are atomically updated at once. Or also have a look at SqlBulk updates.

Answer (score 0):

i have also one suggestion

```
foreach(DataRow item in DataTable.Rows) { 
    //perform update 
}
```

here you can use  LINQ .so it can give fast response

Answer (score 0):

Like Marc already commented, go for option 3, and do a set based update if at all possible (and usually it is). If you think it isn't, maybe you could ask a separate question on how to do that. The more specifics you will give, the better the proposed solutions will fit your situation